# How to appended divs covered by event element

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to append on the event a list of divs. The problem is that the divs display behind the event itself. The `z-index` property doesn't work. Currently the opacity allow to see the divs but they are in the back.

This code is under eventRender

```
  element.find('.fc-bg')
          .append('<br><div style="text-align: center;' + 'z-index: 15;">' +
            '<button mat-button style="width: 80%;' +
            'color: black;' +
            'background-color: lightskyblue;' +
            'font-weight: bold;" id="' + member._id + '" class="employee">' + member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName +
            '</button></div>');
      });
      if (holes > 0) {
        element.find('.fc-bg')
          .append('<br><div style="text-align: center;' + 'width: 80%;' + 'margin:0 auto;'
            + 'background-color: red;" class="holes">'
            + 'Holes: ' + event.holes + '</div>');
      }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default)

Comment: It didn't help. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: maybe something else which is on top of it still has a higher z-index

Comment: Don't know if the z-index hint is true, but if it is, my common workaround is to assign `position: relative` but no offsets with `top` etc. so it is relative to its static position without translation, just elevation.